# How to load a different page properly into my site?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

My Goal:
I have a page with a navigation-box and a content-box. I want to load different pages into my content-box, every time I select a topic inside the navigation box. I´m targeting android and ios devices.

My problem:
I tried many ways to do tho, but none did the job completely.

Ajax - great, but overly complicated to load styles and javascript and to interpret the loaded code to fit it inside the content-box

Iframe - super create, but does make so many problems on ios devices, that it doesn´t work out as well.

Now I´m left with no solution to do the job, anybody any solution here?

Thank you!

Comment: Use Ajax, but redesign how your website works so you don't need to load additional CSS and JS files.

Comment: Thank you Chris for giving me some direction. My site is quite complex, so if I put all the js and css files in one file ore folder it will get really messy and I would lose the track. Any idea to prevent this?

Comment: Yes, use multiple files. Or rethink this approach and create a traditional website instead.